# Error al ejecutar programa en Netbeans al tratar de leer una variable

Tags: c, netbeans, scanf, ejecutar

hace poco empecé a usar Netbeans pero tengo un problema; cuando utilizo "scanf" nunca ejecuta el programa. Por ejemplo:

```
int z;
scanf("%d",&z);
printf("El numero es: %d",z);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Al querer ejecutar el código anterior me aparece lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa parece que se queda atrapado en un bucle infinito y no llega a ejecutar. No solo sucede con scanf, también con gets, fgets, etc. Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando? toda ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: ¿Probaste _tipear_ algo y luego darle Enter?

Comment: si, tengo que presionar enter 2 veces para que imprima el numero. Pero el problema es que si trato de leer 2 valores o mas solo lee uno y se salta el resto